# Difference between two columns into separate rows for each value between the two

Tags: sql, sql-server, transform

I'm having trouble explaining my problem but I have this table

```
ID  START   END
1   10      12
2   30      31
3   11      13
```

and want something like this:

```
ID  NUMBER
1   10
1   11
1   12
2   30
2   31
3   11
3   12
3   13
```

I need the all unique whole numbers between the two columns transform into separate rows.

Here's how I want the transformation to look like

I haven't tried anything because I don't even know how to call such procedure so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a numbers table (highly recommended), you can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.Number 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select Top ([End]-[Start]+1) 
                      Number=[START]-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Number
1   10
1   11
1   12
2   30
2   31
3   11
3   12
3   13
```

Comment: NB. CROSS APPLY is sometimes called LATERAL JOIN (on other platforms.)

Comment: @Hogan "NB"  Haven't see that in some time.  Brings me back to the anguish of my Latin classes.  :)

Comment: John:  ipso facto - I guess I'm getting old.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, [start] as number, [end] as end_number
      from t
      union all
      select id, number + 1
      from cte
      where number < end_number
     )
select id, number
from cte;
```

Note:  If the span can exceed 100, you need `option (maxrecursion)` for the query.

Recursive CTEs are usually a bit slower than a numbers table.  However, I find them much faster than I would expect.

Answer (score -1):

```
--create table NewTable
--(
--ID int,
--NUMBER int
--)
```

DECLARE @ID nvarchar(50) 
declare @START int
declare @END int

DECLARE Cursor_Name CURSOR 
FOR 
    select ID, [START], [End] from tblSequences
    OPEN Cursor_Name
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Name    INTO  @ID,@START,@END
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin

`WHILE @START<=@END
    begin
        insert into NewTable (ID, NUMBER) Values (@ID, @START)
        set @START = @START+1
    end

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Name INTO  @ID,@START,@END
end`

CLOSE Cursor_Name
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Name

select * from NewTable

Comment: CURSORS are always a bad idea in SQL

Comment: @Hogan, yes i agreed, as currently i proposed a solution if applicable then can be used. thanks